# TypeError: 'get binaryType' called on an object that does not implement interface WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, tampermonkey, userscripts

**Hello**, some time ago, i started to make a userscript (tampermonkey script) where i get the active websocket, i have tried to get the websocket when the websocket send a message:

```
let ws;
window.WebSocket.prototype.send = function(){
 if(!ws) {
  ws = this
  console.log(ws)
 }
}
```

but not working, so i tried to handle messages but nothing showing up when a message was received:

```
let ws = window.WebSocket;

ws.onmessage = function(msg){
console.log(msg.data)
}
```

Finally i choosed to get websocket binaryType for reproduce it, but when i send

```
window.WebSocket.prototype.binaryType
```

in devtools, i got this error

```
(in latest Firefox)
TypeError: 'get binaryType' called on an object that does not implement interface WebSocket.
(in latest Microsoft Edge)
TypeError: Illegal Invocation
```

*(i'm not good with English sorry, i'm French)*
**Thanks for answers**

Comment: Userscripts normally need to use `unsafeWindow` instead of `window`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, i have edited my script, code here:

```
let ws;
unsafeWindow.WebSocket.prototype.oldSend = unsafeWindow.WebSocket.prototype.send
unsafeWindow.WebSocket.prototype.send = function(m) {
 if(!ws) {
 ws = this
 alert(ws)
 }
 unsafeWindow.WebSocket.prototype.oldSend.apply(this, [m])
}
//need that for get the websocket
unsafeWindow.WebSocket.prototype.send("ping")
```

This is working, i get the websocket *but*, i got an error:

```
TypeError: Illegal Invocation at WebSocket.unsafeWindow.WebSocket.prototype.send
```

what should i do?

*[UPDATED!]*
Line Error:

```
unsafeWindow.WebSocket.prototype.oldSend.apply(this, [m])
```

was *called on* the *WebSocket object*, *not* in the *window*.
Juste need to replace *.apply* to *.bind*
Corrected Line:

```
 unsafeWindow.WebSocket.prototype.oldSend.bind(unsafeWindow, m)
```